# How to use two arrays to create one string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, web, iteration, navbar

I have this code here:

```
<ul>
<li<?php if ($page == 'home') echo ' class="active' ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li<?php if ($page == 'contact') echo ' class="active' ?>><a href="pages/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
<li<?php if ($page == 'services') echo ' class="active' ?>><a href="pages/services.php">Services</a></li>
<li<?php if ($page == 'employees') echo ' class="active' ?>><a href="pages/employees.php">Employees</a></li>
<li<?php if ($page == 'dashboard') echo ' class="active' ?>><a href="pages/dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I would like to refactor it to pull out some of that repetition. I am working with arrays, and have it somewhere like this:

```
$pages = array(
    "index.php" => "Home", 
    "contact.php" => "Contact Us", 
    "services.php" => "services", 
    "employees.php" => "Employees", 
    "dashboard.php" => "Dashboard");



foreach ($pages as $item) {
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $item) {
        echo 'class="active" ?><a href="' . array_keys($item) . '"> ' . array_values($item) . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . array_keys($item) . '"> " . ' . array_values($item) . '</a></li>';}
```

I can't seem to make it work though. I want it to put the final line together for me add an active class to my nav bar tags when on that page and not otherwise. Is there a reasonable way to do this, and is it good practice?

Comment: How about using `<?php foreach (...):?>` and `<?php endforeach; ?>`?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that aren't quite right:

- That isn't how `foreach` works, `$item` will just be the value.  It does not get set to an array on which you can use `array_keys` or `array_values`. You need `foreach ($pages as $url => $label`
- You're missing the `<li` part of each line.
- You have an extra `?>` in your first `echo`, it should be a `>`.
- You're duplicating a *lot*. The only thing that needs to be conditionally output is the `class="active"' part

```php
foreach ($pages as $url => $label) {
  echo '<li ';

  if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $url) {
    echo 'class="active"';
  }
  echo '><a href="' . $url . '"> " . ' . $label. '</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach ($pages as $item=>$val) {
    echo '<li';
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $item) {
        echo ' class="active" ><a href="' . $item . '"> ' . $val . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '><a href="' . $item . '"> ' . $val . '</a></li>';}
}
```

You have quite some unneeded `.` and `"`. Removed those and you don't need to use `array_keys` or `array_values` if you are using `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($pages as $key => $value): ?>
<?php 
$class = isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] === $key ? ' class="active"' : '';
?>
<li<?=$class?>><a href="<?=$key?>"><?=$value?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```